# make an object with other objects

Tags: c#, user-controls

I created in C#  `textboxes` and some  `comboboxes`. I want them to have in a single object,in order to drag them at the same time. How can I do that? For example,I have this picture. How can I drag all of them at the same time? Thank you!
[image]

Comment: +1 for a very high resolution image.

Comment: What do you mean by 'drag them all at the same time'?

Comment: Perhaps you can put them all on a Panel control?

Comment: Is this what you need? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7b82tya6.aspx

Comment: @BradM lulz at yr comment!

Comment: +1 For the free hand circle!

Comment: Actually @BradM, it's a shame that this was JPG encoded. You can clearly see the compression artefacts. PNG would probably have made the circle clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Either put them all in a Panel of some sort so they can be moved together.
Or create a usercontrol if you need to re-use it.  Just add a new user control to your project and design it like you did for this part of your form. Then add the user control where you need it.